# Does Aptana Studio 3.3.1 support debugging of Python 3.3?

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, aptana, pydev

I am using Apatana Studio 3.3.1 with PyDev 2.7 and writing code in Python 3.3.

I was debugging my code by setting up break point in my code and click on Run>Debug, but the code has not been stopped at the breakpoint and has run through till the end.

In the Interpreter - Python setting, I have included the following in my libraries > System PYTHONPATH:

C:\Python33\DLLs

C:\Python33\lib

C:\Python33

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the run/debug configuration uses the correct main module otherwise it will take the current windows source file to be the main module. If there is no executable code in that file, i.e. there is nothing in global scope, the file will simply run to completion.